# Shopware 6 Plugin: Cypress setup issue with Shopware plugin testing in Docker

Tags: docker, cypress, shopware6

I'm currently working on testing a Shopware plugin, and I'm trying to set up Cypress for testing within a Dockerized environment. I'm following the instructions provided in this [GitHub repository](https://github.com/shopware/e2e-testsuite-platform) for the setup. However, I'm encountering issues when trying to run Cypress.

Specifically, I've tried running the following commands:

- `CYPRESS_baseUrl=http://localhost:3000 npm run open`
- `npm run open`

[image: This is the error]

In both cases, I receive an error message that suggests that `node_modules` is not recognized as a command. I've confirmed that `Node.js` is installed on my system and that I'm in the correct directory where the package.json file is located.

Comment: Which exact error message are you getting? Did you run `npm install`?

Comment: @Alex I have added a picture regarding the error. Yes, I ran the `npm install`.

Comment: General advice: Please try to add text as text, not pictures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are starting the Cypress runner from the wrong directory (...storefront\test\e2e).

Try moving down to the project root, the run one of these:

- npm run open (assumes you have a script named "open")
- node_modules.bin\cypress open
- npx cypress run

There are more details here [Command Line](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line)

I suspect you have a project structure which is slightly skewed from the normal, but you haven't posted any details about that.